# How to remove a knockout observable added by the "extend" option when using ko.viewmodel plugin

Tags: knockout.js

When using the [ko.viewmodel](http://coderenaissance.github.io/knockout.viewmodel/) plugin, how do you remove an observable added using the extend option when unmapping?

Given this example:

```
var model = { name: "test", location: "someplace", items : ["apple","orange"] }

var viewmodel = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(model, {

  extend: {

    "{root}": function(stuff){
        stuff.selectedItem = ko.observable("apple");
    },

    "{root}.items[i]": function(item){
        item.sayHello = function(){
            alert("hello!");
        }
    }

  }

});

var output = ko.viewmodel.toModel(viewmodel);
```

The output object contains a "selectedItem" property which I don't want. How do I go about excluding this extended property when using ko.viewmodel? I want to rely on the plugin's default mapping for every other property within the model (as in another situation the model might be more complex) - I just need to have this extra observable within the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out what I needed to do. Rather than defining a function for each "extend" rule you can pass an object contain both "map" and "unmap" properties to define the extra mapping and unmapping required (but still using the default mapping for everything else). During this unmapping you can manually remove the extra property so it will not appear when ko.viewmodel.toModel is called.

So in my example I need to use:

```
var viewmodel = ko.viewmodel.fromModel(model, {

   extend: {
      "{root}": {
          map: function(stuff){
             stuff.selectedItem = ko.observable("apple");
             return stuff;
          },
          unmap: function(stuff){
             delete stuff.selectedItem
             return stuff;
          }
      },

      "{root}.items[i]": function(item){
          item.sayHello = function(){
             alert("hello!");
          }
      }

   }

});
```